# Correct usage : Papas versus Patatas

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Is it simply Spain is using Patatas and the rest of the world is using Papas?  What is the distinction?

Comment: When the Spaniards arrived to present-day Haiti, in 1526, found the natives called the sweet potato,"batata". Thus when they reached the Inca empire, and heard the natives called papa (Quechua) to potato, then it turned into patata.

Comment: Both words means exactly the same thing, though papas is more used in latam, you could say patata and people would understand you.

Comment: **Papas** is also used on the Canary Islands (Spain)

Comment: Related with comment by user77086, bear in mind that in some places (Argentina) where we say `papa` (and understand `patata`), we also have [batata](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_batatas) to mean "sweet potato" - quite a different thing.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the right answer from user77086, the present day usage is that "*papa*" and "*patata*" are synonyms.

"*Papa*" is the standard word in most of Latin America, Canary Islands and parts from Andalusia. In the rest of Spain the standard word is "*patata*" . In some parts of Spain "papa" is used only for chips ("*papas fritas*") while they use "*patata*" for the potato as it is.

Comment: In Portuguese, the word for potato is "batata" In old French, now considered slang, it is "patate." In modern, French, it's "pomme de terre.

Answer (score 4):

According to RAE both words are valid, just "patatas" is the mainly word used in Spain (except in Canary islands and parts of Andalucia) while many other countries use "papas"

http://dle.rae.es/patata

http://dle.rae.es/papa (second aception)

Comment: @Flimzy Added info to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Papas is also used in Andalucía, southern Spain, but seems to be more colloquial meaning exactly the same as patatas. "Papas asadas" is like baked potatos.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Spain they say "patatas" and where I come from (Mexico) we say "papas"

Answer (score 0):

There's no distinction, but in Colombia, is more often use the word *papas* instead *patatas* for reference potatoes "in any variations":

There's a few examples:

- Un paquete de papas.
- Un bulto de papas.
- Papas a la francesa.
- Papa criolla / Papa boyacense.
- Papa chorreada.

Answer (score 0):

Just that. *Patata* is the word of Spain and *papa* the word of América, Canarias and Andalucía. We all understand both words because TV shows, dubbings and recipes books, mix thosw words but they often use *patata*.